# Angular 5 Data Access to Component from one of the component's child

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-components, angular5

I have below components structure;

- RecipeDetailComponent
- RecipeListComponent

  - RecipeItemComponent ( This Component is child of RecipeList)
- RecipeComponent

and want to pass data RecipeItemComponent to RecipeDetailComponent.
The main way to do that is create @Output() at RecipeItemComponent, get data from RecipeListComponent and  use @Output() too. Finally use property binding to get data from RecipeDetailComponent using @input() via RecipeComponent.

Are There any efficient way or easy way to do that? Do we have to across over parent component to get data from child one to RecipeDetailComponent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide a service at `RecipeDetailComponent` inject it in `RecipeItemComponent` and use it to pass data (ideally using an observable)

Comment: Is RecipeList component child of RecipeDetail? I don't think so. If no, then you cannot use @output for that. You can use outputs only for recipeItem to RecipeList

Comment: The best way to do it is use a shared service between these components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is create a common Recipe service which has passedParamter as an object of type Subject and inject this service in both parent and child components and when i goes to navigate to child component i will notify

```
/// service 


export class SharedService {
  passedParamter: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  notify(data) {
    this.passedParamter.next(data);
  }
}


//// in parent Component

@Component({
    ...,
   providers:[SharedService]
})

export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private SharedService: SharedService){}

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   navigateToChild() {
       this.SharedService.notify(data);
   }
}


//// in child Component

.
.
.
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private SharedService: SharedService){}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.SharedService.passedParamter.subscribe(
           data => {
                /// here you will recive the data
            }
        )
    }
}
```